# Stretch video player with vlc-qt?

Tags: c++, c, qt, libvlc, vlc-qt

I want to make qt application that contains video play function.
Already, I can play video using [VLC-QT Library](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt), and its [Examples](https://github.com/vlc-qt/examples)
Some reason, I want stretch preview.

I found change aspect ratio, but that is only support with enum

```
/*
enum Ratio {
    Original,
    Ignore, !< QML aspect ratio only
    R_16_9,
    R_16_10,
    R_185_100,
    R_221_100,
    R_235_100,
    R_239_100,
    R_4_3,
    R_5_4,
    R_5_3,
    R_1_1
}
*/
Vlc::Ratio r = Vlc::Ratio::R_1_1;

ui->video->setDefaultAspectRatio(r);
ui->video->setAspectRatio(r);
ui->video->setCurrentCropRatio(r);
ui->video->setDefaultCropRatio(r);
ui->video->setCropRatio(r);

ui->video->enableDefaultSettings();
```

**Current:**

[image: Preview]
**I want:**
[image: Want]

How I can configure **stretch mode**?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem, and after my attempts, the following solution is feasible

```
void VlcVideo::setAspectRatio(const QSize& size)
{
    if (_vlcMediaPlayer && libvlc_media_player_has_vout(_vlcMediaPlayer)) {
        auto size_str = QString("%1:%2").arg(QString::number(size.width()), QString::number(size.height()));
        libvlc_video_set_aspect_ratio(_vlcMediaPlayer, size_str.toUtf8().data());
        VlcError::showErrmsg();
    }
}
```

You can keep the same aspect ratio as QWidget in QWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event);