# How do I make VLC scale video to fill window using Python and PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, vlc

So I'm using the python bindings module for VLC on MacOS, using PyQt5 to render the windows.

When I use the VLC GUI it does exactly what you'd expect when you expand a window, scaling the video to fit the window, even when the video is lower resolution than the window.

With the python-vlc moduyle, not so much. Even when it is instantiated with the `--autoscale` option.

In fullscreen mode, videos only fill up about a 1/4 of the screen in the bottom left of the window. In non-fullscreen mode, videos are scaled to the window only after the window is resized manually, and then eventually return to non-scaled.

My goal is to have the video window preserve aspect ratio of the original video and stretch to fill the screen, cropping if necessary.

What option or mystery method am I missing? The documentation seems non-existant. Or is this actually a pyqt option that I am missing?

Forgive the lengthy code excerpt. There are so many idiosyncracies with vlc and pyqt instantiation, I don't see another way to show you what I'm up to.

```
"""
This module contains a bare-bones VLC player class to play videos.
Adapted  from an example by Saveliy Yusufov, Columbia University, sy2685@columbia.edu
"""

import os
import sys
import platform

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import vlc

class Player(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """Stripped-down PyQt5-based media player class
    """

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, master)

        self.media_files = [
            "data/Tv Static Noise HD 720p.mp4",
            "data/070_SHARP_Titles_Flower_Titles.mp4",
            "data/072_SHARP_Footage_Shantyboat_Flyby_Titles.mp4",
            "data/1900 Victorian Time Machine - Parade with Brass Bands (Speed Corrected w_ Sound).mp4"
        ]
        self.current_index = 0

        # PyQy prep stuff
        #
        # set fullscreen mode (we could do this after the object, but let's do this early)
        #
        # in fullscreen mode, videos show up in the bottom left corner
        self.showFullScreen()
        #
        # in this window, videos are scaled only when window is manually resized
        #self.resize(680, 420)
        #
        self.init_ui()

        # VLC prep stuff
        #
        # VLC Options
        vlc_options = [
            "--embedded-video",
            "--no-audio",
            "--autoscale",
            "--fullscreen",
            "--video-on-top",
            "--no-video-title-show",
            "--random",
            "--verbose -1",
            "--canvas-aspect 3:4",
            "--no-canvas-padd"
        ]
        # Create a basic vlc instance
        self.instance = vlc.Instance(" ".join(vlc_options))
        # later used to store media object, for now blank
        self.media = None
        # Create an empty vlc media player
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()
        # self.mediaplayer = vlc.MediaPlayer()
        # Set to fullscreen
        #self.player.set_fullscreen(True)
        #
        # The media player has to be 'connected' to the QFrame (otherwise the
        # video would be displayed in it's own window). This is platform
        # specific, so we must give the ID of the QFrame (or similar object) to
        # vlc. Different platforms have different functions for this
        if platform.system() == "Linux":  # for Linux using the X Server
            self.player.set_xwindow(int(self.videoframe.winId()))
        elif platform.system() == "Windows":  # for Windows
            self.player.set_hwnd(int(self.videoframe.winId()))
        elif platform.system() == "Darwin":  # for MacOS
            self.player.set_nsobject(int(self.videoframe.winId()))

        # load media
        self.open_file(self.media_files[self.current_index])

        # create a timer to refresh video
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(5000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.next_video)

        self.timer.start()

    def init_ui(self):
        """Set up the user interface
        """
        if platform.system() == "Darwin":  # for MacOS
            self.videoframe = QtWidgets.QMacCocoaViewContainer(0)
        else:
            self.videoframe = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        # set videoframe color
        self.palette = self.videoframe.palette()
        self.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        self.videoframe.setPalette(self.palette)
        self.videoframe.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.videoframe)

    def open_file(self, filename):
        """Open a media file in a MediaPlayer
        """
        if not filename:
            return
        # getOpenFileName returns a tuple, so use only the actual file name
        self.media = self.instance.media_new(filename)
        # Put the media in the media player
        self.player.set_media(self.media)
        # Parse the metadata of the file
        self.media.parse()
        # Start playing the video as soon as it loads
        self.player.play()

    def next_video(self):
        self.current_index += 1
        if self.current_index >= len(self.media_files):
            self.current_index = 0
        self.open_file(self.media_files[self.current_index])
        return


def main():
    """Entry point for our simple vlc player
    """
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    player = Player()
    player.show()

    # _ = Client("localhost", 10000, data_queue)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ideally, I want to make a fullscreen player which never resizes to fill the window/screen.

Bonus points if you can offer a tweak to the pyqt codee that removes the need for the vboxlayout. EDIT: Fixed. Thanks @alec

Here's what I see when video plays:

[image: Video emprisoned in bottom left corner]

Comment: can you show a picture of what you're seeing please?

Comment: potentially relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609070/stretch-video-player-with-vlc-qt

Comment: You don't need the QWidget or QVBoxLayout, just make the video frame the central widget.

Comment: @alec I suspected that, but I ran up against my lack of understanding of PyQt and so my attempts to code it failed. When I made the videoframe the central widget, the video did not show at all.

Comment: @alec Thanks, that did it.